# Java code to get all the values in a database table-column

Tags: java, mysql

I need to get all the entries of a column in a database (mysql server) by using java code. Please find the code below:

```
public class DBConnection {

    private String name = null;
    private String path = null;

    public void DbValues(){

        try {
            Class.forName("driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:sqlserver:..",
                    "username",
                    "password");
            if (!con.isClosed()) {
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select name, path from [testtable].[tbl_details]");

                while (rs.next()) {
                    name = rs.getString("name");
                    path = rs.getString("path");
                }
                con.close();
            } else
                System.out.println("failed");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public String getPath() {
            return this.path;
        }
}
```

//in main class

```
public class DBTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        DBConnection dbcon = new DBConnection();
        dbcon.DbValues();
        String path = dbcon.getPath();
        System.out.println("value is .." +path);
    }
}
```

Here it displays only last value of path. Means if it has 20 entry, it will display only 20th value of "path" I need to get all the entries in that particular column. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the values of name and path variable for each entry. Therefore finally you will get the values of last entry.

Add values to some data structure or change your logic

P.S

You can have 2 arraylist for names and paths or one single arraylist of arrays.
e.g.

```
ArrayList<String[]> values = new ArrayList<String[]>();
while (rs.next()) {
     values.add(new String[]{rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("path")});
}
```

Comment: If possible can you please update my code as you said?

Comment: Have given as u said. Gives error this :
 The method add(String[]) in the type ArrayList<String[]> is not applicable for the arguments (String)
 - The method addAll(Collection<? extends String[]>) in the type ArrayList<String[]> is not applicable for the arguments 

and displays suggestion as "addAll()"

--When give addAll() it displays error 

The method addAll(Collection<? extends String[]>) in the type ArrayList<String[]> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: Have done as you said 
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
ArrayList  list1 = new ArrayList();

Created two arraylist--list.add(rs.getString("path"));
list1.add(rs.getString("name"));

added value to arraylists.. Thanks sir